# Manga/Manhua where the MC gains is a mage and gains 1 metre of range for every 10 monsters he kills

Tags: story-identification, manga

Main character does a quiz before starting a game and as a result gains Divine power that allows him to increase his range for every 10 monsters killed. He turns himself into a missile that kills everything from afar.

Answer (score 0):

The Game is Suspended, Only I Know the Invasion of Reality.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please describe this so it's obvious how it matches the question.

Comment: As far as I can tell, only a web novel, not a manga or manhua.